# Pagination with call-api and Dns_Domain getZoneFileContents?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

We are seeing connection resets trying to make the following SoftLayer API call:

dnsManager = getDnsManager()
domainRecord = dnsManager.get_zone('12345', False)

Through the support line we have been recommended to "modify your client to use pagination". But since we expect to only get a single result from that API call (we're requesting that child records being returned is False...), how will pagination help?

Presumably it's a call like "slcli call-api Dns_Domain getZoneFileContents --id=12345 --limit=1" - but that just returns the same result as a non-paginated call.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

According to the support ticket, did you test in other environment?, because I have success with that call using **API_PRIVATE_ENDPOINT** and we don't have any report of issue about the private network or endpoint

> **Updated**

This is an issue with the python dependences.

**Recommendations:**

1. Use virtualenv to create a known good python environment
2. Pip install SoftLayer
3. Run their application inside that virtualenv to test

Comment: It works if you have just a few DNS records. If you have more than a few thousand, then you start to see errors - and need to use the pagination support.